# MacBook Pro won't turn on after Catalina update

Tags: macbook-pro, catalina, software-update, power

I have a 2017 13 inch MacBook Pro without a touchbar.

I upgraded from Mojave to Catalina and left the computer to do its thing. Now about an hour later, my computer seems to be off and won't turn on. It's connected to the charger and had a full battery when I started the update. Now it's basically dead. I've long pressed the power button for more than six seconds and tried short pressing it but nothing. I've tried this several times now.

I'm in lockdown and can't visit an Apple Store either.

**EDIT:**  Steve Chambers' comment about resetting the SMC worked for me. When it restarted, it had Catalina installed. I still do not know what went wrong but hopefully, this helps others who might end up in the same boat.

Comment: Specific MacBook Pro model?  The long press of the power button, was it for at least 5 seconds?

Comment: @Allan it's a 2017 13 inch MacBook Pro without a touch bar. Yes, long press was longer than five seconds

Comment: I should have mentioned to [edit] the original question with the details.

Comment: Do it again, then do a short press

Comment: @Allan, unfortunately that doesn't do anything

Comment: Have you tried resetting the SMC? https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295

Comment: @SteveChambers that worked, thank you! I'm not sure why I had to reset it but once I did, it turned on and Catalina was installed. If you'd like to post your comment as an answer, I will accept it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like it might be fixed by an SMC reset.[Apple: Reset SMC](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295)

And on current Macs this is done like this:

1. Shut down your Mac.
2. Press and hold the power button for 10 seconds, then release the button.
3. Wait a few seconds, then press the power button to turn on your Mac

Comment: Just so you know, I had to press Shift + Control + Option + Power for 10 seconds, let it go and then press the power button. This is one of the options in your link.